# Ex-Employee Published Entire Source Code on GitHub 3 Years Ago - How do we Get it Down?

Tags: employees, intellectual-property

Roughly 3-4 years ago, we hired a PHP developer and tasked them with building small "satellite" websites. They didn't stay long, and we had largely forgotten about them.

Fast-forward to today, one of the sites became big - we've since rewritten the whole thing in another language and open-sourced it on GitHub.

However, now we've found the entire PHP source code of the old site on GitHub, uploaded to the ex-employee's personal account at a time when they were still working with us.

Nobody at the company knew about this or authorized it, not even my boss. It's likely that the ex-employee uploaded it as a "test" without fully realizing what GitHub was. There is no LICENSE or README in the repository.

It would be very difficult to contact the ex-employee, and they might not remove it anyway - so how do we get GitHub to take it down quickly?

Comment: Have you tried contacting GitHub yet? If so, what did they  say; if not, why not?

Comment: Is it likely that GitHub would take it down? Is there any particular strategy to use/law to quote? How do we prove that our company owns that source code?

Comment: File a DMCA notice with GitHub - https://help.github.com/articles/dmca-takedown-policy/

Comment: Have you tried asking the former employee?

Comment: Rather than asking us to tell you if it's likely, ask  _them_ to tell you what's needed. We can't read their minds, we can only read their docs (as @Moo has done).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your interaction with Github is not within the scope of this site. It's likely off-topic on the entire SE network.

Comment: You can extract email addresses from git commits - though this assumes the employee used their personal email address for committing the code rather than a company one.

Comment: Is there anything particularly nonconstructive about my question - does the community feel like I didn't need to ask it/didn't do enough research? Regardless, a discussion has been created around my question - is that constructive/valuable in itself?

Comment: @glcheetham I searched for "copyrighted material on github", and immediately got the answer: "If someone else is using your copyrighted content in an unauthorized manner on GitHub..."

Comment: You're expected to have made some effort to answer questions yourself before asking them here, and asking that service's admins and reading their documentation are obvious  first steps...  so yes, this was nonconstructive. You might want to review how SE differs from other websites; discussion for its own sake is not really what SE is set up for.

Comment: Asking the question here, and drawing upon answers/comments I received has, in fact, helped me to solve my problem. I'll look into specifically _what_ SE was set up for so that I may be able to contribute more constructively again in the future - but if I ask a question and get good answers/good advice in return, I'd consider that to be a constructive use of time

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you do not have a relationship with the developer, or cannot contact them in any way, then the best route for you to take is to issue a DMCA takedown notice.

This absolves GitHub of all legal responsibility for the takedown, and will probably result in the removal of the repository until such time as the account owner files a counter notice.  Without legal responsibility being absolved, it merely becomes a "he said she said" argument which GitHub will not get involved in, as it opens them up to legal issues.

If the account owner files a counter notice, it becomes a legal issue between you and the owner of the account, as they have asserted a claim of copyright ownership or another right which allows them to post the work.  But at least that will clarify the situation for you, and make it obvious what steps you need to take next.

https://help.github.com/articles/dmca-takedown-policy/